# Utilize HP 10GB network card (701525-00) in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, hp

I am trying to build a simple 2 node HomeLab cluster (will eventually add a third node for high availability) using some refurbished DELL workstations. I wanted to try connecting them together with a 10GB network card (again, mostly educational purposes for failing over VMs between nodes with K8 & Proxmox and experiment with high performance cluster filesystems).

But alas, I am stuck even at square zero. The [cards](https://www.ebay.com/itm/255603063091) I have are not being recognized by Ubuntu Linux. They were not expensive so if it fails it's not end of world but I was hoping to learn with them.

This doesn't show anything other than the regular motherboard onboard 1gb ethernet.

```
ubuntu@t7810:~$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: tailscale0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/none 
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Then I tried this to maybe autodetect drivers for install but it said everything is already installed.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

Then I wondered maybe there is a driver on [HP website](https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/product?language=en_US&sp4ts.oid=5404515&kmpmoid=5404513&tab=driversAndSoftware&driversAndSoftwareFilter=8000113)? But alas, maybe nothing for Ubuntu? But the driver software itself is different than the "package" for an operating system, right?

Any hope to have this work with Ubuntu or should I give up on this part and just stick to 1gb ethernet?

Thanks!

Comment: hmm, Its a rebranded x540-t2 apparently, so it might be worth looking up the intel drivers.  There's indications its something called FLEXLOM, and that might need a physical adaptor to work.... I'd also consider if its hardware. Are the link lights lighting up?

Comment: According to the Google cache of this reddit post it is just a generic Intel card and the driver should already be present in kernel. https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:iYCAXxpBvtYJ:https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/dxb8gg/is_this_suitable_for_10gbit_home_server/&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=ubuntu-sn

Comment: Exactly - hence me leaning towards it being electrical since the form factor is different from the 540T2s I own, and there's adaptors for flexlom to pci-e

Comment: Okay, I think that makes sense. Thanks for advice. I'll try to do some research into adapters that can be found affordably.

Comment: Maybe I will try this one since it seems most affordable. If I was a more intelligent person I probably could have went with a different card from the beginning. But I guess this is the first learning of many. Especially if it does end up eventually working with the extra parts. https://www.ebay.com/itm/265894320641

Comment: Its less about 'intelligence' than doing research. Another thing to note with the x540s is its x8, and unless you have an x8 (which is uncommon) electrical or a x16 electrical (and many desktops have x4 with x16 physical), you can't really run both ports at full speed. I use my x540s as single port cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving answer here for anyone and everyone finding this from web search...

The comments from Journeyman were correct. If you purchase the these cards you will need to also purchase an adapter card like I linked to above.

Plug it all in and it just works! It provides you with a solid 10Gb network link between two devices. Speed test measured 9.42Gb. Some overhead is normal I think. For reference, I also setup the regular onboard 1Gb link as a backup and speed test reports that as 753Mb.

Comment: You can speed it up a bit if you enable jumbo frames. Also, the 'older' x540s off aliexpress are comically cheap.

Comment: You are right! Thanks for the tip. That increased it to 9.89Gb!

Comment: Yeah, it is surprising how much recycled server e-waste is available so cheaply. For less than a thousand dollars I feel like I got enough hardware to run a SaaS startup from my garage.

Comment: Its not ewaste if it works :D